# Log ActiveRecord Model changes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, model

I'm trying to find a way to keep track of model changes in an efficient and 'smarter' way from what I'm doing right now.

I have a DB of about 80.000 Objects which get updated every hour.

Currently i'm using the [paper_trail](https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail) gem for versioning. Similar solutions out there are
[audited](https://github.com/collectiveidea/audited), [vestal_versions](https://github.com/laserlemon/vestal_versions) etc..

What was clear from the beginning was that my DB was going to be big. But after only 3 days in action my DB has already a size of 1.2GB , with 5 Tables.

What i need basically is to keep track of 3-4 variables of an Object and track them over a period of one Month. That means about 720 Versions (1 version every hour).

What would be a good way to manage that kind of data in an efficient way? Is it wise for example to create 15 variables and populate them with 2 Days of Data ? That would mean the same amount of data with no extra rows. At the beginning i had those thoughts, but i don't know if that's such a good Idea.

What other ways would you suggest me ? What are good practices when dealing with such large Datasets ?

```
# Further Information:

- Ruby on Rails 4.1.4
- Ruby 2.1.2
- PostgreSQL 9.3.4

All attributes are integers
```

Comment: If you want to "trim", you'll probably need to roll your own solution. Do you have a sample of the 3-4 variables you want to track on every change? What database are you using?

Comment: Yeah Probably. All variables are integers, except from 1-2 strings. I'm thinking of creating maybe a STATS object that belongs to the object and just create an attribute for every hour. That would leave me with one big chunk of attributes for every Object. I don't know, it's kinda messy in my head right now. I can't form a clear picture.

Answer (score 0):

**What about keeping it that way?** You say you need those data for one month. 1.2 GB in three days means 12 GB of data at the end of the month. That may seems big, but for MySQL or Postgres or any other, it's not. In other words, what it the exact problem here (a large DB is not one). Does it impact your performance or something else?

**Trim what you can**. If you need only a small subset, make a custom audit log with just the variables you need. If this is for metric purposes, 720 rows should certainly not amount to a lot of space. Another option is to already combine them into statistics (for example, version each day, make an agregation at the end of the week and delete the daily data, and repeat).

Comment: Trimming is what i'm thinking of right now. It is for Statistical purposes and i need the whole month. Think of a Graph showing hour-by-hour and day-by-day changes. 12 Gb is certainly HUGE for me. As i'm tapping into this i don't think i can handle managing correctly such Data. I'm searching for ways to maybe combine some Data in a smarter way to get rid of a lot of extra Rows. And talking about performance, querying that Data should be pretty expensive. But i guess 'Trimming' is the magic Word. Only that i need a smart way to do it.